# How to use checkbox in a report in oracle apex to insert values in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a table call **OUTGOING** which has many fields but the ones to be populated in this situation is:

- FILENUMBER
- OUTGOINGDATE
- DEPARTMENT

now i have a report which whas an sql

```
 SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(1,registry.filenumber) "Select",

  INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION.REQUESTEDFILE as REQUESTEDFILE,
    INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION.FILENUMBER as FILENUMBER,
    INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION.REQUESTEDDEPARTMENT as REQUESTEDDEPARTMENT,
    INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION.REQUESTDATE as REQUESTDATE,

    REGISTRY.STATUS as STATUS 
 from REGISTRY REGISTRY,
    INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION 
 where REGISTRY.FILENUMBER(+) =INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION .FILENUMBER
and INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION.STATUS ='PENDING'
```

which is fine .. what i need is for

- INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION.FILENUMBER as FILENUMBER
- INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION.REQUESTEDDEPARTMENT as REQUESTEDDEPARTMENT
- and sysdate

to be inserted in the outgoing table under the relevant names of course.

I have a pl/sql

```
 DECLARE
  L_FILENUMBER WWV_FLOW_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
BEGIN
  L_FILENUMBER := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01;
  FOR IDX IN 1 .. L_FILENUMBER.COUNT
  LOOP
    IF L_FILENUMBER(IDX) IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO OUTGOING
     (FILENUMBER,OUTGOINGDATE,DEPARTMENT)

VALUES
((to_number(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1)))     
   ,SYSDATE
,to_char(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(2))  )

     ;

    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

which is not working.. However if i leave only filenumber

```
DECLARE
  L_FILENUMBER WWV_FLOW_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
BEGIN
  L_FILENUMBER := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01;
  FOR IDX IN 1 .. L_FILENUMBER.COUNT
  LOOP
    IF L_FILENUMBER(IDX) IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO OUTGOING
     (FILENUMBER)

VALUES
((to_number(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1)))     

     ;

    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

its inserting only the file number fine . This is all being done via a submit button.

NB: i also tried putting outgoing date and department in the declare statement but it still doesnt work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to learn how to use table aliases. `SELECT` you wrote is difficult to read due to VERY long table & column names; alias would certainly help.

As of your question: saying that "it is not working" doesn't help at all. What exactly doesn't work? Is there any error? If so, which one? Did you run the page in debug mode and check what's going on? If not, do that.

Apart from that, code you wrote doesn't make much sense - you're trying to insert the same values all over again. E.g. shouldn't `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1)` be `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(IDX)`? Something like this:

```
begin
  for idx in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count
  loop
    if apex_application.g_f01(idx) is not null then
       insert into outgoing 
         (filenumber, 
          outgoingdate, 
          department
         )
         values
         (apex_application.g_f01(idx),
          sysdate,
          apex_application.g_f02(idx)
         );
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Check (by *inspecting* the page) whether (tabular form?) items really are those that you've used (`G_F01` and `G_F02`). If not, you'll have to fix that.

I didn't use any `TO_NUMBER` nor `TO_CHAR` functions; I don't know whether your really need them. Even if you don't have them, Oracle will perform implicit datatype conversion when possible, but it'll fail if you try to put e.g. 'abc123' into a `NUMBER` datatype column. You didn't share that information so - I left those out. Apply them if necessary.

Comment: (1) noted on your first point(aliases)...                                                                                     (2) By saying "its not working am not"  am getting "no data found"                             
(3)Its a report with a select check box (not a tabular form).                                                           am new to oracle only 7 months so am learning as i go along.... i tried your code but am getting no data found

Comment: when i remove  apex_application.g_f02(idx) i am getting the file number and the sysdate to insert as it should. So am thinking i should have a rowid checkbox which should select the whole row and insert it ... I dont know but if it is so can you show me the correct statement for it

Comment: Why do you use a **report** to insert data? Use **interactive grid** (or a tabular form I mentioned previously) - they are meant to be used for *inserting* data. As of NO_DATA_FOUND: it is raised if g_fxx doesn't contain anything. Did you check whether you correctly use g_fxx (by inspecting page elements)?

Comment: i edited the above question to include a picture of the page. I change to interactive grid. can you see the issue from this?

Comment: Apart from seeing an interactive grid, nope - sorry, I don't see any issue in that.